# ASP.NET download script is loading current page file as the download file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a script in ASP.NET for downloading a file from my database. When I click on the download button, the file loading for download is title with name of the page my download button is and the file is saved as a .aspx file instead of a .docx as it was originally saved when I uploaded it.

Please I need your assistance to get this solve.

```
protected void Download(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Request-Id"] != "")
    { 
        string fileName = getFileName(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Request-Id"]));

        if (fileName != "") { 
            Response.ContentType = "Application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";  
            Response.AppendHeader("content-deposition", "attachment/filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("/Uploads/" + fileName));
            Response.End();  
        }
    }
}

protected string getFileName(int id)
{  
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbCall"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Conveyance_Document from Convey where Request_Id = @Id", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(id));

    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (sdr.Read())
    {  
        string fileName = sdr["Conveyance_Document"].ToString();
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        return fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.* See [mcve]

Comment: this question could have been answered very easily as it's already been asked *many* times http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+download+file+asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";  
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("/Uploads/" + fileName));
Response.End();
```

The header name is `Content-Disposition`, not `content-deposition`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is working properly. Please can you help me on something else please

Comment: Yes I'll try to help you. But please validate my answer as it resolved your problem. Add another question if you have another problem.

Comment: Please i need to a web service in asp.net that will be running in the background of my application to do a check on user response. This is how it goes. When some enters a log, the log needs response from a particular department. So i need to do a background check to see if the log has been responded to by the department. If not after 24hours, i will have to send an email to another department to remind them to respond. My problem is i don't know how to create the background service to do the checking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer validation. Add a question explaining exactly what you want to achieve and what you tried to achieve your goal. I cannot help you like this in comments.

Comment: You can do a Console or WebForm application that does the checks and sending emails if needed. Then set a Windows Scheduler running every hour for example launching your application.

Comment: Thanks so much, i really appreciate.